# Android Facebook events invite

Tags: android, facebook, events, invite

I'm developing an android application where I have to invite facebook friends to an event using Rest API.

Below is the code where I prepare bundle of parameters

```
   Bundle eventInviteParams = new Bundle();
   eventInviteParams.putString("method", "events.invite");
   eventInviteParams.putString("eid", event.getFacebookEventId());
   eventInviteParams.putString("personal_message", "Sample message");

   String userIds = "";
   for (int i = 0; i < facebookAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    FacebookUser user = facebookAdapter.getItem(i);
    if (user.isSelected()) {
        userIds += user.getId() + ",";
    }
   }
   if (userIds.length() > 0) {
    userIds = userIds.substring(0, userIds.length() - 1); // to remove last comma
    eventInviteParams.putString("uids", userIds);
   }
```

Then

```
response = mFacebook.request(eventInviteParams);
```

where `mFacebook` is Facebook api object.

The response is always

> {"error_code":200,"error_msg":"Permissions
>   error","request_args":[{"key":"uids","value":"XXXXXXXXX,XXXXXXXXX"},{"key":"method","value":"events.invite"},{"key":"format","value":"json"},{"key":"eid","value":"XXXXXXXXXXX"},....]}

Application has following permissions

```
"email","publish_stream","read_stream","create_event","offline_access","user_events","friends_events","rsvp_event"
```

I want also to mention that I'm not event creator. I have searched on FCB docs and google but cannot find a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for your response. 
I continued with research and I found that the error

```
"error_code":200,"error_msg":"Permissions error"
```

was because I was not following the event. Once I RSVP to the event, I got the response `false` (I don't know why) and the error gone. I checked in Facebook and the given people were invited.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only the user that has created the event can invite people to it. Even if the user has created the event with "Guests can invite friends" it seems that it is impossible to do it from an app. A few weeks ago I tried several methods to no avail!

Answer (score 0):

The events.invite api is broken ..check it out on the facebook bugzilla http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=17057